# 404 error while trying to upgrade

Tags: upgrade

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While we want to help answer you question, this question doesn't have any actual question text, just some info, so we don't really know how to help your specific problem. If you could post what exactly you want help with, then maybe we could help you solve this problem.

Comment: i think its a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hardy is no longer supported, you should remove that line for your etc/apt/soucres.list

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: see the second links in my comments

Comment: can u type the command line on how to do that?

Comment: gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list   --find the failed line and delete it.